# Why does Word 2016 create a huge file when exported to pdf?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, microsoft-word-2016

I have 15 MB Word file that creates a 55 MB when exported through Acrobat. We cannot figure out why this is happening.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you only export part of the file? Say it is 30 pages and you export the first 10. Is the resulting size then 55/3 MB or smaller? Using a search like this might help identify the problem.

Comment: Tried Word's own Save As>PDF? How is the file created by this?

Comment: If the word file is linking to file resources elsewhere (i.e. images) and not embedding them, then that 5MB may not include that data which has to be embedded in the standalone PDF.

Comment: Is that 1.5 MB or 15 MB?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem here: PDF and DOC are two different file formats with different purposes that accomplish different things. It is normal for there to be significant variation in size between two "identical" files in the different formats.

Just to name a few of the differences that add up to size differences:

- PDFs embed fonts and other elements so that they'll display EXACTLY the same on any computer.
- DOCs do not embed fonts and so if you view a DOC on a computer lacking a font the document was created with, it will look different.
- DOCs apply mild compression to their most recent version, the DOCX file.
- PDFs do not compress the file at all.

PDF size can also vary substantially based on HOW you create the PDF. Different engines will convert the documents different ways and therefore even the "exact same" PDF could be different sizes. Even Word 2016 allows the selection of "Standard Publishing" and "Minimum Size" as options when creating PDFs from DOCs.

So, there is not an issue here, though it may be worthwhile to determine what the purpose of the files are and decide whether there are reasons to use one file format over the other in each situation.